# simple question in calculus but not enough english

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

There is a bee on a stacker which is on the plane $xyz$. The plane equation given is: $$2x+y-2z=1$$

The equation of the direction at a time $t$ of bee is $$r(t) = t\hat i + t^2\hat j + t^3\hat k$$

1. What is all time that bee flies parallel to xyz?
2. What is all time that bee flies perpendicular to xyz?
3. There exists some points that bee is able to go out from the swatter (hole). What are the coordinates of this hole?

Comment: For parallel, you need make cross product zero,

Comment: For going out from the hole of swatter, it needs to be.. ? Parallel to the swatter, right?

Comment: bee needs to be perpendicular to the hole. I have just added the image link to explain a bit clearly. Sorry for my English..

Comment: Yup, so you need to find the foot of perpendicular. Your language is correct, my question was for you.

Comment: what was the topic of this course? I actually didn't attend the online course due to Corona pandemi. How can I search it? and how can I make a cross product with r(t) and xyz plane..? Really thanks for your assistance for this process

Comment: Learn to calculate cross and dot products, study 3D geometry, planes and lines, finding foot of perpendicular, etc...

Comment: I actually couldn't solve could you help if possible really thanks..

Comment: This is the basics. Do you know how to take dot and cross product of two vectors?